# Displaying EPSG:32649-WGS 84 image on EPSG:4326 map in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, image, epsg

I have a image has EPSG:32649 coordinate system and I want to display this image on a  EPSG:4326 map on arcgis desktop (ArcMap).

Any one can help me?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply add your EPSG:32649 image to a data frame that has its coordinate system already set to EPSG:4326.

On-the-fly projection should take care of displaying it in the correct location.

If you need to set a transformation, then doing this should trigger a warning for you to do so.

Also, pay attention to the [comment by @mkennedy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158667/displaying-epsg32649-wgs-84-image-on-epsg4326-map-in-arcmap#comment234917_158674):

> The image needs to have a coordinate system defined for it, if it
>   doesn't, you should get a warning about that too. Use ArcCatalog to
>   define the coordinate system if it's missing.